# Does constant writing to "files" in `/proc` or `/sys` reduce the life of my SSD due to its limited number of writing cycles?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, proc, ssd

My laptop has a SSD drive and I run a script which writes every other second to `/sys/class/thermal/cooling_device4/cur_state`. I don't think this would count as writing to the SSD and thus reducing its remaining number of writing cycles, since `procfs` and `sysfs` are virtual filesystems.

Or am I overlooking something and this is an issue?

Comment: You are right. Not writing to the SSD doesn't count as writing to the SSD. The same would hold for a RAM drive such as `tmpfs`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're entirely correct: virtual filesystems like `procfs` and `sysfs` are not stored on disk at all. Their contents are generated on-demand based on kernel data structures in RAM, and writing into them (if possible at all) translates into making changes to in-memory kernel settings.

Writing to `procfs` or `sysfs` cannot possibly have any impact to SSD lifetime.

Comment: But if I'm nit-picking, is that possible writing to /sys control the state of your SSD controller so it will have some impact to the hardware?

Comment: No, repeated writing to `/sys/class/thermal` (as the original poster asked) won't have any impact to SSD hardware :-)  To have any significant effect, you would have to write into `/sys/block/<device name>/` and basically deliberately pick the worst possible settings for a SSD. Even so, modern consumer SSDs have plenty of writing cycles and efficient wear leveling: typically the vendors promise that you could write more than a terabyte _every day_ and the SSD would still have the expected lifetime. Of course, sometimes those promises can be mistaken or less than truthful otherwise...